# Django send_mail() only spits two arguments... I want three

Tags: django

I cannot seem to find an answer in Stackoverflow so I decided to post the issue.

I am using django send_mail() and I include the NAME, EMAIL and MESSAGE but for some strange reason only NAME and EMAIL get sent. Basically, the third argument gets ignored and I cannot figure out why.

CLARIFICATION: the email sends and works flawlessly, but I cannot get Django to spit the third argument for message.

This is my code:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        message_name = request.POST['message-name']
        message_email = request.POST['message-email']
        message = request.POST['message']

        send_mail(
            'Email from ' + message_name,
            message,
            message_email,
            ['myemail@gmail.com'],
            )

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        return render(request, 'base/index.html', {'message_name': message_name})

    else:
        return render(request, 'base/index.html', {})
```

Comment: add ```print(request.POST) ``` to see if your message somehow is empty in your request.POST

Comment: You shouldn't try to use the `from_email` argument with a value from a form. Instead, include that in the message of the email, and set `from_email` to some static email address that's associated with your domain. Otherwise you risk driving up your spam score.

Comment: Hi @schillingt, can you be more specific? I cannot understand your help :)

Comment: The `from_email` property is the email address that the email is being sent from. If the `message_email` can be any email address your smtp server will be impersonating that email address when it sends the email. This will cause your spam score to increase.